# Wolfram Mathematica 9 can't start

Tags: mathematica

When I start Mathematica 9, dialog with "Choose a MathLink program to launch" appears.When i cancel the dialog, Mathematica will stop. I've found that this could happen when Mathematica is used with own C++ programs, but I don't use it that way, I just want to start Mathematica. 
I tried to uninstall and remove specific directory as it is written [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/4730) and install again with no success.
What should I do?

EDIT:

When I cancel the dialog, this message dilog appears:

```
Serious startup error

Mathematica could not establish a connection to the kernel.
Kernel: System.
Low-level MathLink error: Unknown internal error.
```

Comment: Its not clear what the problem the behavior you describe sounds perfectly normal consider the program closes after you cancel launching Mathematica.

Comment: I've made an edit to the question - when I cancel the dialog which shows up on startup, I got "Serious startup error" message, with only "Quit" button.

Comment: What operating system are you using exactly?

Comment: Windows 8.1 x64. First run was ok.

Comment: So what software have you removed since the very first time you ran it?

Comment: Nothing, I have just installed SQL server update and restarted computer.

Comment: Does Mathematic require SQL Server to be installed?  If it does you have found the reason its not working.

Comment: No it doesn't. I've found [this similar problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32232/mathematica-sporadically-crashes-on-open) with no solution.